# Maximum of finite $L^p$ functions is in $L^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be an arbitrary measure space and $u_1, \dots, u_n$ be $L^p$ functions, $1\le p <\infty$. Then $w=\max\{|u_1|, |u_2|, \dots, |u_n|\}$ is also in $L^p$.

I know how to show this in the  case of $p=1$, but for $p>1$, I am stuck on how to show this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you already know that sums of $L^p$ functions are $L^p$? Because the maximum is a sum of a certain collection of $L^p$ functions...

Comment: @Ian yes I do know the first fact, but is there a way to describe the maximum of $n>2$ functions like the case for $n=2$?

Comment: No it's not but you can use induction argument.
$u_1,u_2 \in L^p$ so is $a_1 = \max\{|u_1|,|u_2|\}$, then $a_2 = \max\{|u_1|,|u_2|,|u_3|\} = \max\{a_1,|u_3|\}$ is also in $L^p$, etc…

Comment: You can: $\max \{ u_1,\dots,u_n \}=\sum u_k 1_{A_k}$ where $A_k$ is the set where $u_k$ is the biggest.